# Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 crashes on M1 Monterey 12.5.1

Tags: android, android-studio, macos-monterey

I just updated from Monterey 12.5 to 12.5.1.

However, after that Android Studio (`android-studio-2021.2.1.16-mac_arm.dmg`) no longer starts.

I get the following error message:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000107d72e38, pid=92768, tid=259
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.12) (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, bsd-aarch64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0x6d2e38]  AccessInternal::PostRuntimeDispatch<G1BarrierSet::AccessBarrier<1097844ull, G1BarrierSet>, (AccessInternal::BarrierType)2, 1097844ull>::oop_access_barrier(void*)+0x8
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/Tom/java_error_in_studio_92768.log
[thread 74759 also had an error]
[thread 91395 also had an error]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

The content of `/Users/Tom/java_error_in_studio_92768.log` is a little long to post here, but does not give any deeper insights (at least for me).

Anybody having the same problem?

Comment: Seems to be working fine in here I have the same m1 monterey 12.5.1 the only thing different for me is i installed the android studio before the update and then update.

Answer (score 0):

I updated to the release candidate of the next version called "Dolphin" which is the file "android-studio-2021.3.1.15-mac_arm.dmg".

Now it works again as it should.

Comment: this version is still beta till now,
https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2022/07/android-studio-dolphin-beta-5-now.html